# What is smooth compactification?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let X be a smooth irreducible curve over a separably closed field k. Then is there smooth projective curve $\bar X$ over $k$ which admits an open immersion $X\hookrightarrow \bar X$?

This question comes from a book $\it{Etale\ Cohomology\ theory}$(Lei Fu) proposition 7.2.10. In the book, there's no definition for the word "curve", so I assume it means a scheme of finite type over a field $k$ with dimension 1.

Comment: Yes, this is true. One solution: embed your curve in some projective space, take the closure, resolve the singularities of the closure by taking blowups of your projective space, which works since blowing up is projective.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks to your comment, I've found Stacks 32.42. This seems to provide what I want to know, but the only question is whether we need separated assumption. A "curve" should be a scheme separated of finite type over k with dimension 1?

Comment: This is a very common thing to assume.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for your help!

Comment: @KReiser: when you say that you 'embed the curve in some projective space' do you use the 'embed' synonymously to 'immersion'? that is the composition of a closed followed by open immersion?