# Question on Smooth Completion of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-curves, projective-schemes

Let $X$ be a smooth irreducible curve of finite type
$C$ over a  separably closed field $k$.
For such curves is known that they always have a smooth compactification, that
is there exist a smooth projective curve $\overline{X}$ over $k$ which
contains $X$ as *open immersion $X \hookrightarrow \overline{X} $.

Due to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_completion#Construction) or [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409173/what-is-smooth-compactification) roughly
the construction works as follows: Assume we can embed our $C$ as
*locally closed* immersion in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$.

(How to manage it? If $C= Spec(R)$ is affine, then since it have finite type we get
a closed immersion $C \hookrightarrow_c \mathbb{A}^{n}$
induced by quotient $k[x_1,..., x_{n}] \to R$ and clearly there exist
open immersion
$\mathbb{A}^{n} \hookrightarrow_o \mathbb{P}^{n}$. If $C$ is not affine then
we decompose $C= \bigcup V_i$ in
affine open subschemes $V_i = Spec(R_i)$ where
these are by finite type assumption given as closed immersions
$V_i \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^{n_i}$ via qoutients
$k[x_1,..., x_{n_i}] \to R_i$. I think we can assume that the number of
$V_i$ is finite and therefore chose $n:=n_i$ to be independent of $i$. Then
we could somehow arrange the $\mathbb{A}^{n_i}$ to be the affine cover
of $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ and argue as before module some technical gaps; optimizations and advices always welcome. nevertheless assume for now $C$ is *locally closed* in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$)

Next we take Zariski closure $\overline{C}$ of $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$.
If $\overline{C}$ is not smooth, then we can resolve the singularities, but this step is not important for my question.

Question: The aspect which I haven't understood right now is why
is $C$ *open* in $\overline{C}$. Clearly it is dense by construction
but I not see any reason why it should be open.

Again, let $\bigcup_i U_i$ be a affine open cover of $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ such
that $V_i = C \cap U_i \hookrightarrow_c U_i$ are closed immersions.
I want to show that $V_i = U_i \cap C \hookrightarrow U_i \cap \overline{C}$
is an open immersion but don't know how to manage that.

Comment: Do you care about $C$ being an open subscheme of $\overline{C}$, or just an open subset?

Comment: About this point I wasn't sure myself, *according to wikipedia* in the link
the smooth completion requires $C$ to be just open set 
of $\overline{C}$, but of course I think that (at least for curves) 
it is reasonable to require $C$ to be open subscheme of
$\overline{C}$. I don't know, reading your comment& answer I think that
since $C$ is assumed to be smooth it is enough to require $C$ to
be only open subset, by construction $C$ becomes *here* automatically 
open subscheme of $\overline{C}$.

Comment: In general it seems to be highly more subtle as you remarked. Daniel used nowhere
that $C$ was a curve, so it seems always to be true that topologically
every $k$-scheme $X$ of finite type (that means that it's affine pieces 
locally are closed subschemes in
some $\mathbb{A}^n$) is as *set* open in $\overline{X}$ but in general 
not as an open immersion, for this we should require more; compare with
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata%27s_compactification_theorem

Comment: but here $C$ is moreover open immersion because  for a smooth (so reduced) curve it should be work  because here we can our immersion also factor as open by closed composition as remarked in your answer

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there *is* something going on here, depending on your definition of a locally closed immersion. The definition of a locally closed immersion according to most sources (i.e. EGA) is a closed immersion in to an open subscheme, and swapping the order of these so that the immersion is an open immersion in to a closed subscheme requires either reducedness of the source or quasi-compactness of the morphism, both of which we have here. See [07RJ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07RJ) for details - the key is that either condition lets us compute the scheme-theoretic image affine-locally.

Let me point out that you never have to worry about this for varieties, or more generally any noetherian scheme - any map from a noetherian scheme is quasi-compact, and therefore satisfies the conditions above.

Comment: I don't think this subtlety matters here, though—the question of whether $C$ is open in $\overline{C}$ is purely topological, so we can just ignore the scheme structure entirely, right? And topologically the order of these doesn't matter, it's just the intersection of an open subset and a closed subset in both cases.

Comment: When I read the OP, I don't think they're asking for a purely topological thing because their final paragraph asks for an open immersion. Maybe I'm wrong though - I'll leave a comment and ask.

Comment: Oh, I think you're right, if you want to guarantee that it's an open immersion it looks like you do need some extra scheme-theoretic input like this.

Comment: @Daniel & Hank: Thanks for the very informative discussion, when I was asking
this question I wasn't aware about this subtlety that in general
that it's not the same for a immersion to be be defined
as a composition of an closed by open immersion (That's as far I 
found here https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IM the *standard*
notation)
or as composition of open by closed immersion (indeed the later seems not
to exist always, but for reduced $C$ we it exists and we can swap the order
 of open and closed; as $C$ is smooth,

Comment: it's reduced and at all finaly that 
doesn't matter although it *is* very interesting how far it can be generalized). So in summary one can say that if $X \to P^n$ is an immersion in first sense, then
$X$ is *always* open subset of $\overline{X}$ but we should impose
some additional conditions if $X$ should also be open immersion
in $\overline{X}$ (which for example a smooth (therefore reducible) curve
has)?

Comment: By the way: If in context of algebraic geometry we say
that we *embed* $X$ in $Y$ 
(like in a comment by KReiser here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409173/what-is-smooth-compactification)
should this always be understood as synonymous to an *immersion* 
in the sense above? Or is there any difference?

Comment: If you're working with noetherian schemes (such as varieties over a field), you can automatically interchange open and closed immersions because every map out of a noetherian scheme is quasi-compact. So you can feel free to relax about all of this nasty business! And if you see someone say "embed" and you're not sure what they mean, you should probably ask them.

Answer (score 1):

This is immediate from the fact that $C$ is locally closed in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Indeed, let $X$ be any topological space, and let $Y \subseteq X$ be a subset. Then $Y$ is locally closed if and only if $Y$ is open in its closure $\overline{Y}$ (with the subspace topology).

Indeed, by definition, a locally closed subset is the intersection of an open subset and a closed subset. If $Y$ is locally closed, then there exist open $U \subseteq X$ and closed $Z \subseteq X$ such that $Y = U \cap Z$; then we also have $Y = U \cap \overline{Y}$ by the definition of closure. Conversely, if $Y$ is open in $\overline{Y}$, then by the definition of the subspace topology, there is an open set $U \subseteq X$ such that $U \cap \overline{Y} = Y$, so $U$ is locally closed in $X$.

Comment: nice, so there is nowhere algebraic geometry involved (only in next steps to make it smooth by blowups...), just pure topology, thanks +1

Comment: Right, this part is pure topology. The involvement of algebraic geometry is in making it smooth by blowups, and also in constructing the locally closed embedding into projective space in the first place.

Comment: Actually, there is a (potential) subtlety about immersions here - it was too long for a comment so I added it as an answer.